# Why does Firefox 'grey-out' and stop working?

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Why does Firefox 'grey-out' and stop working and then the color scheme becomes normal and resumes working?  This grey-out period can last from 10-60 seconds.  Hardware includes HP 8440p with 8GB RAM and SSD.  I would think that this configuration / model is well suited for 16.04: the system monitor indicates that 20% of RAM is used, with Firefox has ~5 windows

## UPDATE:

The upgrade to Firefox Quantum has resolved the overheating, speed and freezing issue.

Comment: That happens when there's not enough RAM available. What kind of laptop are you using? Which brand and model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [program windows fade to grey and get then normal again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/542937/program-windows-fade-to-grey-and-get-then-normal-again)