# Ubuntu 17.04 installed on a USB flash drive freezes so much

Tags: usb-drive, 17.04

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu. It freezes so many times during my work and the screen fades out for many seconds. I use it on a separate USB flash drive in Acer Travelmate PC. Help please.

Comment: Ubuntu is dimming application windows and running unresponsively because you're not giving Ubuntu much in the way of hardware to run on. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542937/program-windows-turn-gray-and-then-go-back-to-normal-again/542983#542983) for recommendations about how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with using normal usb's for installing ubuntu. I found the same problem when I installed ubuntu on to a usb. However, as soon as I put it onto my computers hard drive, it sped up a lot.

If you really want to put ubuntu onto a usb, I would get at least a usb 2.0, but probably a 3.0. They are much faster, therefore making the os run faster.

## Important:

Make sure that your computer/laptop supports USB 2.0/3.0. Otherwise you won't get any difference in using USB 2.0.

See [here](http://www.cablestogo.com/learning/library/standards-specs-certs/when-to-use-usb) for a comparison of the different versions of USB