# Periodic pauses in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I went from Ubuntu 16.04 (unity) to Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, and I'm getting periodic freezes.

Everything's going fine, I'm playing a browser game and listening to a YouTube video in the background, then the music, game, keyboard, and cursor freeze **for a half second, then unfreeze** (unlike 90% of reports of hanging). It happens every 5 minutes, sometimes less.

I don't see any noticeable CPU spike, and there's nothing notable in the syslogs. How do I go about tracking down the cause of the problem?

Possibly relevant:

```
x0a@hp-lp:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6620G]
    DeviceName: AMD Radeon(TM) HD 6620G
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6620G]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
x0a@hp-lp:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Pilot6 My PC doesn't hang indefinitely (that would require hard reset). It just pauses, then unpauses.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Pilot6 Thanks for the suggestion. Done

Comment: What are other specs of your comp? How much RAM you have, what is the CPU, etc.

Comment: It's a HP Pavillion g7-1277dx laptop, with upgraded quad-core 1.9 ghz A8-3530MX AMD APU, 8GB ram, 7200 rpm SATA 3 drive. I installed the propietary microcode which seemed to help some

Comment: Which pointing device are you using? Is it a mouse or a touchpad?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program windows turn gray and then go back to normal again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542937/program-windows-turn-gray-and-then-go-back-to-normal-again)

Comment: Pilot6 I'm using a generic wired mouse (the $5 mouse from Amazon)
karel I don't think this is a low-resource problem because it was working fine in my previous Ubuntu installation, and no such problem occurs in Windows. I have the system-monitor applet enabled so I'm constantly watching RAM and cpu usage, I don't see anything out of the ordinary.