# Window Freeze in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, freeze

In my ubuntu 14.04 sometimes some windows start to freeze when I try to close them the system starts to become unresponsive. It is also impossible to kill these windows.

This it could be related to an update? Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program windows turn gray and then go back to normal again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542937/program-windows-turn-gray-and-then-go-back-to-normal-again)

Comment: Can you post your system specs: RAM, CPU details, ect. Also, can you post more details about when it happens, when I had this problem it was when I had a lot of programs open and a lot of chrome tabs.

Answer (score 0):

just happened again, this is what dmesg show:

> [72241.260112] INFO: task fsnotify_mark:200 blocked for more than 120
>   seconds. [72241.260120]       Tainted: P           OX
>   3.13.0-143-generic #192-Ubuntu [72241.260123] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs"  disables this message.
>   [72241.260127] fsnotify_mark   D ffff88086fcb3b00     0   200      2 
>   0x00000000 [72241.260135]  ffff880856eb7ce0 0000000000000046
>   ffff880856eb8000 0000000000013b00 [72241.260144]  ffff880856eb7fd8
>   0000000000013b00 ffff880856eb8000 ffff880856eb7e10 [72241.260151] 
>   ffff880856eb7e18 7fffffffffffffff ffff880856eb8000 0000000000000000
>   [72241.260158] Call Trace: [72241.260171]  []
>   schedule+0x29/0x70 [72241.260178]  []
>   schedule_timeout+0x279/0x310 [72241.260188]  [] ?
>   native_sched_clock+0x13/0x80 [72241.260194]  [] ?
>   sched_clock+0x9/0x10 [72241.260201]  [] ?
>   sched_clock_local+0x1d/0x80 [72241.260208]  []
>   wait_for_completion+0xa6/0x150 [72241.260213]  [] ?
>   wake_up_state+0x20/0x20 [72241.260221]  []
>   __synchronize_srcu+0xfe/0x180 [72241.260226]  [] ? call_srcu+0x70/0x70 [72241.260232]  []
>   synchronize_srcu+0x1d/0x20 [72241.260240]  []
>   fsnotify_mark_destroy+0x87/0x150 [72241.260247]  []
>   ? prepare_to_wait_event+0x100/0x100 [72241.260252] 
>   [] ? fsnotify_put_mark+0x40/0x40 [72241.260259] 
>   [] kthread+0xcb/0xf0 [72241.260266] 
>   [] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
>   [72241.260274]  [] ret_from_fork+0x6e/0xa0
>   [72241.260280]  [] ?
>   kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0 [72241.260384] INFO: task mel:8754
>   blocked for more than 120 seconds. [72241.260388]       Tainted: P
>   OX 3.13.0-143-generic #192-Ubuntu [72241.260390] "echo 0 >
>   /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs"  disables this message.
>   [72241.260393] mel             D ffff88086fc53b00     0  8754   7704 
>   0x00000004 [72241.260398]  ffff88007de63cf0 0000000000000082
>   ffff88041bd4b000 0000000000013b00 [72241.260405]  ffff88007de63fd8
>   0000000000013b00 ffff88041bd4b000 ffff88007de63e20 [72241.260411] 
>   ffff88007de63e28 7fffffffffffffff ffff88041bd4b000 ffff88085886a160
>   [72241.260418] Call Trace: [72241.260424]  []
>   schedule+0x29/0x70 [72241.260430]  []
>   schedule_timeout+0x279/0x310 [72241.260439]  [] ?
>   mod_timer+0x10e/0x230 [72241.260445]  [] ?
>   add_timer+0x18/0x20 [72241.260451]  []
>   wait_for_completion+0xa6/0x150 [72241.260456]  [] ?
>   wake_up_state+0x20/0x20 [72241.260462]  []
>   __synchronize_srcu+0xfe/0x180 [72241.260467]  [] ? call_srcu+0x70/0x70 [72241.260472]  []
>   synchronize_srcu+0x1d/0x20 [72241.260478]  []
>   fsnotify_destroy_group+0x1e/0x40 [72241.260484]  []
>   inotify_release+0x22/0x50 [72241.260490]  []
>   __fput+0xe7/0x260 [72241.260495]  [] ____fput+0xe/0x10 [72241.260501]  [] task_work_run+0xaf/0xd0 [72241.260508]  []
>   do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0 [72241.260515]  []
>   int_signal+0x12/0x17