# If you disable wobbly windows, does that decrease GPU consumption?

Tags: compiz, performance

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I've just disabled *wobbly windows*. Will this effectively make my computer run better? I also disabled the water effect.

Comment: No. Compiz effects are irrelevant to how fast the PC is.

Comment: @mikewhatever That doesn't seem right at all, but perhaps you mean by comparison to other changes the OP could make, or perhaps this really is a case where disabling something that requires significant processing to carry out nonetheless yields no performance improvements (which is rare... but possible, in theory). Would you be willing to post an answer to clearly explain and support what you are saying here? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good.

Comment: @EliahKagan In my opinion, Compiz effects in 16.04 are well balanced between usability, appearance and resource usage. They are not "freaky visual effects and eye candy [that] eats computer hardware resources". The "wobbly windows" effect is not enabled by default, but having it enabled would do nothing significant to the GPU/CPU usage. I am sorry if it doesn't seem right to you.

Comment: @mikewhatever At this point, I have no idea why you haven't posted an answer. I very much recommend doing so. You could even use the exact text of your comments, if you wanted. It seems to me that "well balanced between usability, appearance and resource usage" is not the same as, or even consistent with, "irrelevant to how fast the PC is." But that doesn't mean your overall point is wrong. Since you haven't posted an answer, the one we have now (which I didn't write and haven't, at any point, assumed correct) likely appears uncontested. Your comments (and mine) may even be deleted eventually.

Comment: My issue is that I'm running an old setup from the core 2 duo days and it will barely run YouTube properly. I just want to be able to play a video game without the screen going grey for five minutes. I disabled wobbly windows and water effect, but should I disable anything else to increase performance?

Answer (score 4):

Enabling freaky visual effects and eye candy eats computer hardware resources. Disabling them will make it seem that the computer is running a little bit faster. To prove it compare the different flavors of Ubuntu. The minimal desktop environment flavors of Ubuntu require less hardware resources than vanilla Ubuntu.

If the applications windows keep [dimming to gray](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542937/program-windows-turn-gray-and-then-go-back-to-normal-again) and then go back to normal again, it could be due to **insufficient hardware resources** because a Raspberry Pi or any new computer that is bigger than a Raspberry Pi can play YouTube videos properly. Try either running a more lightweight Ubuntu edition like Ubuntu MATE 16.04 or adding more RAM to your computer. Or wait another month and try Ubuntu MATE 18.04. Remove an existing RAM stick from your computer and take it with you when you shop for a new RAM stick to make sure that the new RAM stick is compatible with the existing RAM stick(s). Don't invest too much money in upgrading an old computer because new computers have become almost as cheap as new phones.