# Gnome SHELL turn off unresponsive window warning

Tags: 14.04, gnome

This question is almost the same as

- [How do I turn off the feature where a window grays out when it's thinking?](https://askubuntu.com/q/128921/65285)

with one difference. I'm using the GNOME Shell desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 and therefore, the solution given in the linked Q&A does not work.

Does someone know, how I can turn off the unresponsive warning and the graying out of the window?

[image]

The main problem is that *Mathematica* even in version 10.3 does something weird, when you have dynamic content and you move a slider for more than a few seconds. Somehow the desktop environment thinks that the window does not work anymore (although it does) and shows this warning in the middle of your work.

The most unfortunate thing is that when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, like I do in my IDE when I want a dialog to disappear, the whole program is killed and all unsaved work is lost.

Comment: @muru You are right. This is certainly the same issue. Please don't tell me that I have to recompile Gnome to get rid of this message :(

Comment: If you look at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981149#c12, it looks that way. Not the whole of GNOME.